# Reading the contents of Microsoft Visio (2010) doc in IronPython

Tags: ironpython, visio

I have an assignment to write a program in IronPython, that reads a Visio (2010) Document, and outputs in CMD what objects are in the active page, and how they are connected to each other.

So far, I have managed to open the Visio Document, but I can't display what's in it.
This is my code until now:

```
import sys
import clr
import System
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio
IVisio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio
visapp = IVisio.ApplicationClass()
doc = visapp.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\hari\\Desktop\\PythonExamples\\helloworld.vsd") 
page = visapp.ActivePage

elements = page.GetContainers(0)

for entry in elements:
    print entry

doc.Close()
visapp.Visible =0
visapp.Quit()
```

I found the method GetContainers in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765392(v=office.15).aspx but it's not outputing anything about the shapes that exist in the document. Does someone maybe have an idea?

Comment: I changed your tags as the problem is (up until now) not related to python (and not even really to ironpython) and added a visio-tag as so seem to primarily require assistance with the visio SDK/automation API.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456831/shape-connectors-in-visio
There is no big difference if you do that in python or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with something like this... it's pretty straightforward I suppose..

```
.......
.......
page = visapp.ActivePage

for shape in page.Shapes:
    if not shape.OneD:
        print shape.Name + " '" + shape.Text + "'"
        for connectedShapeId in shape.ConnectedShapes(2, ""):
            connectedShape = page.Shapes.ItemFromID[connectedShapeId]
            print " => " + connectedShape.Name + " '" + connectedShape.Text + "'"
```