# Extract graph elements from Visio document using php or python

Tags: php, python, visio

I store a network graph(basically nodes and links) in database. I have some portions of network in a Visio files.
Is it possible to extract nodes and links form this files using PHP or Python?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to query visio shape information (shape types, text, connections, etc) programmatically.

Visio provides COM API which you can use form any language which can call COM API, python for example (using e.g. either .NET module (clr) or win32com module).

Here is a similar question:
[Reading the contents of Microsoft Visio (2010) doc in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439603/reading-the-contents-of-microsoft-visio-2010-doc-in-ironpython)